# Error: Model is asking for column 'id' but $key is set to different else

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `genre_books` set `provider_id` = ?, `genre_id` = ? where `id` is null) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 466284, ))
```

It's adding some data successfully but in that table but it still gets this error around in the middle of updating.

Model:

```
class GenreBook extends Eloquent {

    public $table = 'genre_books';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $publicKey = 'book_id';

    public function setRank($a) {
        $this->sort_order = $a;
    }

    public function setProviderId($a) {
        $this->provider_id = $a;
    }

    public function setBookId($a) {
        $this->book_id = $a;
    }

    public function setGenreId($a) {
        $this->genre_id = $a;
    }

}
```

Code in controller:

```
GenreBook::unguard();
foreach($bookList as $genreId => $books) {
     if(count($books) > 0) {
    foreach ($books as $book) {
         $genreBookRecord = GenreBook::where('book_id',$book['asin'])->where('provider_id',3)->first();


         $newGenreBook->setProviderId(3);
         $newGenreBook->setBookId($book['asin']);
         $newGenreBook->setRank($book['rank']);
         $newGenreBook->setGenreId($genreId);
         $newGenreBook->save();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eloquent assumes that the `primary key` is `id` so all you need to do is set your primary key like so :

```
 protected $primaryKey = your primary key
```

Comment: Yes I know that fact. I see so it's not $publicKey but $primaryKey, thanks man!